# IE radio button ignoring margin=0

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, radio-button

I'm trying to make `radio` buttons look the same in both **IE** and **Firefox**.

I have the following example:

```
<head>
<style media="screen" type="text/css">    
    html, body, div, form {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    input{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;    
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<span style="font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-size:8pt;">
    <input type="radio" name="blah" value="7">MyWord<br>
</span>
</body>
```

In **IE** the `radio` button **has an extra white space where the margin should be `0`**. So the text, which should be really close to the `radio`, is not.

I know I that if I use the `DOCTYPE` statement it works, but due to other problems, I can't use it.

Is there any other way to fix this problem?

Comment: why can't you use the doctype statement ?

Comment: because it's going to break other stuff in the code.. :)

Comment: what if you add :

span { margin:0;padding:o; } ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the width of the radio button element to a sufficiently small value:

```
<input type="radio" name="blah" value="7" style="width: 13px">
```

The spacing you see is neither padding nor margin but part of the rendering of the radio button (as you can see if you press F12 in IE, then find the element under “HTML” and look at the layout description—the element).

It seems that browsers generally implement radio buttons and checkboxes as 13 × 13 pixels (in total dimensions), except IE in Quirks Mode, which uses 20 × 20, unless the dimensions are set otherwise in CSS.

Comment: **IE-10**: Adjusting `padding-right` worked ok (0-3px).